# Protecting application url

Tags: security

How do I protect the url generated by my application?

example

http://www.mydomain.com/jsp/get_article.jsp?id=1

how do I make these url unreadable to human beings?

Comment: "unreadable to human beings", "protect" and "make secure" are all different. What threat are you trying to protect from?

Comment: This is a bad idea because it will make your pages harder for search engines to index while providing no real "security"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use a hash such as http://www.mydomain.com/jsp/get_article.jsp?hash=[base32 MD-5 hash value] or similar. Then you have a table hash -> article on the server (as hashes are unique enough, you don't have to care about "clashes" between the hashes of different articles). Of course, you would still have to have the hash on the client side, so you either have to calculate it there, or you have to simply give it within the page.

The hash would be the hash over the article itself, so it will be unique for the article at all times, and cannot be guessed without knowing the actual article. Titles are too easy to guess.

Howevery you look at it, you will not get perfect security from this, but you can get security from people trying to guess the URL without requesting the page before it. In other words, it's a lot of work without too much gain. But as you are trying to achieve a DRM scheme, it's probably the best you can get...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "unreadable". I think the short answer is: It can't be done. The URL has to be visible to the browser or how will it request the resource? Your question sounds a little like saying, "How can I let people call me without telling them my telephone number?"

You could, I suppose, encrypt your URLs. But why?

If there is information in the URL that you don't want the user to see, then ... don't put it in the URL. Like, if you had a customer help system that directs users who give impossible answers to the "moron" section of your system, I wouldn't make the url be "http://example.com/help/moron.jsp?screen=17". Call it something non-descript. More seriously, you certainly should not make the customer's password or other confidential information part of the URL. Keep this sort of thing in data on the server side that is accessed via "safe" data, like a user id.